# return value from callback function to send client response

Tags: node.js, async-await, callback, middleware

I have a middleware that it should send the request to a function, wait for it to finish and send back to the client what that function returns. the problem is I dont figure it out how to return the value that I'm getting inside a cb, hence the response is always an empty array.

```
const insertMultiDoc = async function (req, res) {
  const documents = await uploadMultipleFiles(userData, documentsList, index);
  res.send(documents);
}
```

here is the middleware func simplified, so documents is always an empty array. I dont return correctly from the below function

```
const uploadMultipleFiles = function (userData, documentsList, index) {
    let savedDoc;
    let savedDocuments = [];
    
    if (pathHelper.ensureDirectoryExistence(randomFilePath)) {
        mv(documentsList[index].path, randomFilePath, async function (error) {
            if ((userData.email !== undefined) && (userData.component !== undefined) && (userData.email != "") && (userData.component != "")) {
                var tempFileFolderPath = pathHelper.createSpecificPath(userData.component, userData, uploadTime);
                var randomFilePath = path.posix.normalize(tempFileFolderPath + "/" + generatedFileName);
                var inputPath = randomFilePath + '.' + fileExt;
                var outputFileFFmpeg720 = tempFileFolderPath + '/720p' + generatedFileName + '.' + fileExt;
                var encodedFilePath = pathHelper.createDBPath(userData.component, userData) + "/720p" + generatedFileName + "." + fileExt;
                var accessFilePath = pathHelper.createDBPath(userData.component, userData) + "/720p" + generatedFileName + "." + fileExt;
                
                const output = await fileCompresser.compressFile(inputPath, outputFileFFmpeg720);
                fileSize = await getSize(output);
                newDoc = createNewDocumentObject(userData.senderId, userData.senderUsername, userData.email, userData.component, userData.sessionId, fileName, fileType, accessFilePath, encodedFilePath, null, fileSize, userData.parentComponent);
                savedDoc = await documentController.createLocalDocument(newDoc);
                fs.unlinkSync(inputPath);  
                index = index + 1;
                console.log(savedDoc);
                savedDocuments.push(savedDoc);
            }
        })
    }
return  savedDocuments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this situation I use `q` module

```
const q= require('q');
const uploadMultipleFiles = async function (userData, documentsList, index) {
    let defer = q.defer(); // create a defer
    try {
        let savedDoc;
        let savedDocuments = [];
        if (pathHelper.ensureDirectoryExistence(randomFilePath)) {
            mv(documentsList[index].path, randomFilePath, async function (error) {
                if ((userData.email !== undefined) && (userData.component !== undefined) && (userData.email != "") && (userData.component != "")) {
                    var tempFileFolderPath = pathHelper.createSpecificPath(userData.component, userData, uploadTime);
                    var randomFilePath = path.posix.normalize(tempFileFolderPath + "/" + generatedFileName);
                    var inputPath = randomFilePath + '.' + fileExt;
                    var outputFileFFmpeg720 = tempFileFolderPath + '/720p' + generatedFileName + '.' + fileExt;
                    var encodedFilePath = pathHelper.createDBPath(userData.component, userData) + "/720p" + generatedFileName + "." + fileExt;
                    var accessFilePath = pathHelper.createDBPath(userData.component, userData) + "/720p" + generatedFileName + "." + fileExt;
                    
                    const output = await fileCompresser.compressFile(inputPath, outputFileFFmpeg720);
                    fileSize = await getSize(output);
                    newDoc = createNewDocumentObject(userData.senderId, userData.senderUsername, userData.email, userData.component, userData.sessionId, fileName, fileType, accessFilePath, encodedFilePath, null, fileSize, userData.parentComponent);
                    savedDoc = await documentController.createLocalDocument(newDoc);
                    fs.unlinkSync(inputPath);  
                    index = index + 1;
                    console.log(savedDoc);
                    savedDocuments.push(savedDoc);
                }
            })
        }
        defer.resolve(savedDocuments); // return result
    } catch (error) {
        defer.reject(error) // return error
    }
return defer.promise; //return a promise
}
```

you can check the `q`  [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)